# Datagridview to excel - Late Binding

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to incorporate the following [Codesample](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiEx8_DSigw23h6Cj) in terms of the way the 'Flipdatagride' button works in rotating the data from horizontal to vertical which is c#

At this moment my data in [My Application](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiEx8_DSigw23h6Cj) created in vb.net 2013 is the datagridview is being presented horizontally with a single column header along the top with the inputting text in either my textbox's or clickbox under each single header with a row based.

This is the codesamples conversion from c# to vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
Private ops As New Operations
Private ds As DataSet = Nothing
Private dt As DataTable = Nothing
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = New DataSet()
    dt = New DataTable()

    dt = GetCustomers()
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim my_DataView As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = my_DataView
End Sub
Private Function GetCustomers() As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.TableName = "Customers"

    table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))

    table.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mohamad", "1700", "Egypt"})
    table.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Tarek", "550", "Syria"})
    table.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Gamal", "762", "Saudi Arabia"})

    table.AcceptChanges()

    Return table

End Function
Public Function FlipDataSet(ByVal my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i))
        Next
        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next

        ds.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds
End Function
Private Sub butFlip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butFlip.Click

    Dim currentDataSet As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds) ' Flip the DataSet
    Dim currentDataView As DataView = currentDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataView

    butFlip.Enabled = False
    butNormal.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub butNormal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butNormal.Click
    Dim currentDataSet As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataSet

    butFlip.Enabled = True
    butNormal.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub butExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub butExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butExport.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSheetName.Text) Then
        Select Case ops.ExportDataTable(CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataView).Table, txtSheetName.Text)
            Case OperationResults.Success
                MessageBox.Show("Data written to file")
            Case OperationResults.SheetExist
                MessageBox.Show("Sheet already exists, aborted")
            Case OperationResults.UnknownException
                MessageBox.Show($"Operation throw an exception{Environment.NewLine}{ops.Exception.Message}")
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
    End Class`
```

What i'm trying to achieve is that upon the user selecting the button 'generate' in my application it will firstly flip the datagrid to vertical and the export to excel in the same format using the following code from the above codesample;

```
Private Sub butFlip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
butFlip.Click

Dim currentDataSet As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds) ' Flip the DataSet
Dim currentDataView As DataView = currentDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
DataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataView

butFlip.Enabled = False
butNormal.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub butNormal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
butNormal.Click
Dim currentDataSet As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
DataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataSet

butFlip.Enabled = True
butNormal.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

And:

```
    Public Function FlipDataSet(ByVal my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i))
        Next
        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next

        ds.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds
End Function
```

So far i've got this but button2 'Flipdata' is just making the datagridview blank with a column header called '0'. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
Dim table As New DataTable(0)
Public checkBoxList As List(Of CheckBox)
Private ds As DataSet = Nothing
Private dt As DataTable = Nothing
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = New DataSet()
    dt = New DataTable()
    ds.Tables.Add("Table")
    Dim my_DataView As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = my_DataView
    table.Columns.Add("Forename", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Surname", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Food", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    checkBoxList = New List(Of CheckBox) From {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim currentDataSet As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds) ' Flip the DataSet
    Dim values As String = "" &
    String.Join(" & ", checkBoxList _
    .Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).Select(Function(cb) cb.Text))

    ' use values for placing into your DataGridView
    CheckBox1.Text = values
    CheckBox2.Text = values
    CheckBox3.Text = values
    CheckBox4.Text = values


    table.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, values.ToString)
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 100
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

    'Save to excel with headers
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
        Next
        For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
            .cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells("Forename").Value
            For j = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
            Next
        Next

    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    '
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
Public Function FlipDataSet(ByVal my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i))
        Next
        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next

        ds.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim currentDataSet As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds) ' Flip the DataSet
    Dim currentDataView As DataView = currentDataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = currentDataView

    Button2.Enabled = False

End Sub
End Class`
```

Comment: Could you precise your question? You paste some code but it is not clear what is not working or what function do you need.

Comment: @smartobelix all i'm trying to accomplish is making my uploaded application rotate the datagridview information from horizontal to vertical as shown in the codesample.

Comment: Update in original thread! Help please!